# How to remove an installed package using go modules

Tags: go, go-modules, vgo

I've installed a package using go modules (go get in Go 1.13) and now I want to remove it. In the [documentation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/vgo) there is nothing about this and in [go get docu](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/get/) neither.

Removing the package from go.mod manually doesn't solve the issue so it remains in go.sum.

How should I remove a package in a clean way?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Found it [https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules#removing-unused-dependencies](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules#TOC_7.)

`go mod tidy`

So basically, once the package is not being imported in any package you can perform a `go mod tidy` and it will safely remove the unused dependencies.

And if you are vendoring the dependencies, then run the command below to make the module changes be applied in the vendor folder:

`go mod vendor`

Comment: Module not in go.mod but still in vendor dir!

Comment: @sope have you execute it with the GOFLAG -mode=vendor? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-do-i-use-vendoring-with-modules-is-vendoring-going-away

Comment: Seems to remove code generating modules (that aren't used directly in the code, only in `//go:generate` comments) is there a way to preserve those modules?

Comment: This does not remove modules in go.sum

Answer (score 6):

@jesugmz answer doesn't say, what if you wanna remove a currently using package in go modules.

So, if you're using go modules (you have a `go.mod` file in your project) and you want to remove a currently using package, check `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/` directory and simply remove the package named `package@version`.

For example, if you have `github.com/some/project` package installed, you should run the following command:

```sh
rm -rf $(go env GOPATH)/pkg/mod/github.com/some/project@v1.0.0
```

You can find the using package version in `go.mod` file.

Comment: Also run `go clean -modcache` to remove module cache.

Comment: For yuks, you might want to verify that `$(go env GOPATH)` doesn't return something empty, or otherwise awful.

Answer (score 2):

If you used `go install package@latest` then to remove:

`go install package@none`

`go clean -cache -modcache`

When in VS Code `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and select `GO: Restart Language Server`

Comment: This is the right command