# go get : There is no tracking information for the current branch

Tags: git, go, go-get

When I type in the command  `go get -u github.com/ndelphit/apkurlgrep`

I get the error

> There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please
> specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for
> details
>
> ```
> git pull <remote> <branch>
> ```
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so
> with:
>
> ```
> git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
> ```
>
> package github.com/ndelphit/apkurlgrep: exit status 1

Comment: i can't repro this error... have you done anything to your environment?

Comment: That error comes from git, you probably have a corrupt clone cached locally

Comment: @kylieCatt no, I don't remember if I installed it using apt as a dependency for another program or if it comes with ubuntu. But I didn't touch anything in the environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of digging, I found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/201). One suggestion was to delete src from the go directory and this worked for me.

So here is what I did (Linux):

1. Find the go folder (for me it is located in the home directory) and cd into it

   `cd go`
2. List the contents of the go folder

   `ls`
3. You should see the src folder, now delete it:

   `rm -rf src`
4. Try the go get command again (for your package)

   `go get -u github.com/ndelphit/apkurlgrep`
5. You shouldn't get the error, run the package that you have installed (in my case apkurlgrep) to see if it has been installed. It runs!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your local Go version and if you are doing the command from a go project (with its `go.mod`), or outside any project.

Inside a project, try a [`go clean -modcache`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58225534/6309), and your

```
go get github.com/ndelphit/apkurlgrep
```

Comment: I've not tried this as I already found a solution, thank you though!

Comment: Ok. I will remember this the next time I install something with go.

Comment: its mr again. When I use go install I get  ``` go: finding module for package github.com/akamensky/argparse
go: found github.com/akamensky/argparse in github.com/akamensky/argparse v1.3.1
```

Comment: @Ferdinand I just tested the command( *outside* of any Go project): it works without any issue/error.

Comment: I'm doing it in a blank terminal(not cd'd into any directory)

Comment: @Ferdinand What version of go are you using?

Comment: go version go1.17.8 linux/amd64

Comment: @Ferdinand And what error message do you see when you use `go install`?

Comment: ```go: finding module for package github.com/akamensky/argparse ``` and ```go: found github.com/akamensky/argparse in github.com/akamensky/argparse v1.3.1``` This is the output I get

Comment: @Ferdinand So... it worked! Meaning in `$HOME/go/mod/github.com/ndelphit`, you should be able to find the library installed.