# Is there a `go uninstall`?

Tags: go

As stated, I get that `go install` copies the executable to `{GOPATH}/bin` but is there such a thing as `go uninstall`?

After `go clean`, the executable is still in `{GOPATH}/bin`; I found nothing in the docs, bar a rather blunt force `rm -f {filename}`.

Comment: *"is there such a thing as `go uninstall`?"* -- No, there isn't.

Comment: `go install` installs a single binary. To uninstall, just delete the binary.

Comment: Similar question for packages with `go get` from a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792254/removing-packages-installed-with-go-get   StackOverflow used to be a kinder place....

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Removing the installed executable with `rm` is the right way to go.

In Go, `go install` builds a single-file binary and "installs" it by copying it to the appropriate directory (*). To "uninstall" this binary, simply remove it with `rm`.

It may feel "blunt force" to you, but it's actually reassuring if you think about it. There's little magic involved. Installation means a single binary gets placed in some directory (which is likely in your `$PATH`).

See also [this answer for a relevant discussion of removing packages installed with `go get`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792254/removing-packages-installed-with-go-get)

---

(*) From `go help install`:

> Executables are installed in the directory named by the GOBIN
> environment variable, which defaults to $GOPATH/bin or $HOME/go/bin if
> the GOPATH environment variable is not set. Executables in $GOROOT are
> installed in $GOROOT/bin or $GOTOOLDIR instead of $GOBIN.

Comment: Thank you very much Eli,
you are of course right, that the single executable is very re-assuring, compared to some of the crud attached to things like .NET etc, I was just really wanting to make sure that is the correct thing to do 

considering I want to use docker & CI/CD on my golang projects this actually simplifies things immensely

Comment: For other users who found this answer non-straightforward, go installation (for Mac) is usually in /usr/local/go. Delete this go folder to completely uninstall.

Comment: It would be great if a "go uninstall" command not just removes the resulting binary, but also all the downloaded repos to build it.

Comment: Yes - how to remove all installed deps?